# Sudden "already initialized constant" errors when running rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization, rake, rake-task

I've been running rake tasks no problem for a while, on a Windows machine. Then I suddenly started getting an error when I ran anything rake-related. It happened for the first time after I ran `rake db:migrate`, and I think that may have been after I altered a migration without rolling it back first. Now, every rake command gives this:

```
> rake db:rollback

c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::RUBY
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: previous definition of RUBY was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LN_SUPPORTED
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: warning: previous definition of LN_SUPPORTED was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT was here
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::ARRAY_METHODS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: previous definition of ARRAY_METHODS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::MUST_DEFINE
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: previous definition of MUST_DEFINE was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::MUST_NOT_DEFINE
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: previous definition of MUST_NOT_DEFINE was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::SPECIAL_RETURN
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: previous definition of SPECIAL_RETURN was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DELEGATING_METHODS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: previous definition of DELEGATING_METHODS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::GLOB_PATTERN
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:86: warning: previous definition of GLOB_PATTERN was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:381: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:381: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:387: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:387: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Rake::VERSION
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::MAJOR
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of MAJOR was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::MINOR
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of MINOR was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::BUILD
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of BUILD was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::OTHER
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of OTHER was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::NUMBERS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NUMBERS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/linked_list.rb:110: warning: already initialized constant Rake::LinkedList::EMPTY
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/linked_list.rb:110: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/scope.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Scope::EMPTY
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/scope.rb:41: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/promise.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Promise::NOT_SET
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/promise.rb:12: warning: previous definition of NOT_SET was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:13: warning: already initialized constant Rake::CommandLineOptionError
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:13: warning: previous definition of CommandLineOptionError was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Application::DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:41: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_RAKEFILES was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:108: warning: already initialized constant Rake::EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:108: warning: previous definition of EMPTY_TASK_ARGS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Rake::InvocationChain::EMPTY
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:55: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/early_time.rb:21: warning: already initialized constant Rake::EARLY
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/early_time.rb:21: warning: previous definition of EARLY was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/late_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::LATE
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/late_time.rb:17: warning: previous definition of LATE was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SYS_KEYS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:4: warning: previous definition of SYS_KEYS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SYS_PATHS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:5: warning: previous definition of SYS_PATHS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESSED_PATHS
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:8: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESSED_PATHS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESSED_PATHS_RE
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:12: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESSED_PATHS_RE was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESS_PATTERN
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:16: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESS_PATTERN was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb:70: warning: already initialized constant FileList
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb:70: warning: previous definition of FileList was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb:71: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb:71: warning: previous definition of RakeFileUtils was here
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/load_error.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant LoadError::REGEXPS
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/load_error.rb:2: warning: previous definition of REGEXPS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant ActiveModel::Validations::Clusivity::ERROR_MESSAGE
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb:6: warning: previous definition of ERROR_MESSAGE was here
```

I found a few related threads saying that the problem was that I needed to type "bundle exec" before the command. I've never had to do that before, but I tried it. I got a shorter, but similar, error:

```
> bundle exec rake db:rollback

c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/load_error.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant LoadError::REGEXPS
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/load_error.rb:2: warning: previous definition of REGEXPS was here
c:/ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant ActiveModel::Validations::Clusivity::ERROR_MESSAGE
c:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb:6: warning: previous definition of ERROR_MESSAGE was here
```

Anyone know what's causing this?

---

UPDATE

For some reason my computer was confused about the location of Ruby, so I had to reinstall everything locally instead of globally like so:

```
bundle install --path vendor/cache
```

Comment: How is this error _similar_ to the previous one? `bundle exec` is necessary to ensure that the local gemset is used. The latter error message clearly says how to resolve the issue.

Comment: @mudasobwa That gem error was a separate thing that's been showing up for a while. I should have deleted those lines from the my question, but in any case I now added the gem and updated the error output I'm getting.

Comment: Is Windows’ file system (is it still NTFS?) case sensitive? I wonder what does mean `Ruby24-x64` vs `ruby24-x64` in your logs. If yes, you might want to delete one of them.

Comment: @mudasobwa Strange, I'm not sure why it's writing "ruby24-x64". I only have `Ruby24-x64` on my computer.

Comment: Well, that seems to cause the issue. It somehow distinguishes `R` and `r` and hence tries to read the files twice.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeah, that appears to have been the problem. I reinstalled everything locally instead of globally and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, my server was confused about the casing of my Ruby folder, and seemed to think there were two, although there weren't. I had to reinstall everything locally in my app instead of globally, like so:

```
bundle install --path vendor/cache
```

and it works with no warnings now.